# Writing a mutex for accessing a shared text file in MATLAB parfor

Tags: matlab, mutex, atomic, parfor

I have a FORTRAN code which takes the value of a few parameters through an input file and based on that it runs and finally produces an image. Later, I am doing some post processing on that image and calculating a value as per my requirement.

Since my fortran code takes around 20 secs to generate one image therefore to make it faster, I tried to use `parfor` for one of the parameter(`dep`) so that I could calculate each row of the matrix `dist` on separate processor. The problem is, while running this code, each processor is trying to write to the input file and thus causing chaos among themselves with the error `Txt file busy`. Also the program gets stopped abnormally.

Below is my code section:

```
matlabpool open
gray1 = some_image(8192,200);

dep = 0.04:0.01:0.40;       % Parameter 1
vel = 1.47:0.01:1.72;       % Parameter 2

dist = zeros(length(dep),length(vel));

parfor i = 1:length(dep)

    for j = 1:length(vel)

        % Updating the Velocities.txt file
        fid=fopen('input_file.txt','w');
        fprintf(fid,'%-5.2f\n%-5.2f',dep(i),vel(j));
        fclose(fid);

        % Compiling and running my fortran code to generate another .dat file

        system('gfortran code.f -o coderun');
        system('./coderun');

        % Calling IMAGE_GEN script incorporating the above .dat file 
        system('IMAGE_GEN');

        gray2 = some_image(8192,200);

        % Doing some mathematical calculations and getting a value say 'EucDist' 
        ans(j) = EucDist; 

        display('Calculation finished');

        fclose('all');
    end

    dist(i,:) = ans;

end
matlabpool close

end
```

Can someone please suggest me a way to write a mutex for this `write` atomic operation or any other alternative way to run my script over the available 12 workers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could make each `parfor` loop create an input file with a different name.

You could then modify your fortran code to read the input file name from a command line input argument.

I included a code snippet i used to test the idea below:

```
% Dummy input data;
dep=[2 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8];
vel=[1 2 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8];


% Compile the modified fortran code here. 
system('gfortran code.f -o coderun');    

parfor i = 1:length(dep)
  for j = 1:length(vel)
    fname=['input_file_' num2str(i) '.txt'];
    fid=fopen(fname,'w');
    fprintf(fid,'%-5.2f\n%-5.2f',dep(i),vel(j));
    fclose(fid);

    % Your other code goes here.

    % Call the executable 
    system(['./coderun ' fname]); % Pass the filename as an input argument
  end
end

% Clean up the input files
delete('input_file_*.txt');
```

Comment: It's a nice idea but MATLAB is again producing errors for my fortran code ` `code.f `, saying `Text file is busy`. I think I need to make different copies of my fortran code and the corrosponding `.dat` file as well which it is producing after running but that seems to be a tedious task. Is there any method to overcome that?

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: I updated my previous answer. The file `code.f` doesn't seem to change, so it would probably make more sense to perform the compilation just one time, before the actual `parfor` loop.

Comment: Yeah...exactly. I'll do that and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: This idea seems to be working but I am encountering some other problems caused by the generation of few other intermediate files like `.psv` `.out` files before formation of the actual `.out` file. Do I need to create these files also differently for different workers?

Comment: Not that familiar with fortran compilation processes. What do you mean by 'other problems'?

Comment: No. Actually it's not like fortran creates all those files during its compilation process. It's just that I am creating those intermediate files to get my actual final image. By 'other problems' I mean that since parfor is not able to create those `.psv`  `.out` files therefore it is throwing error for some random line in my actual  MATLAB script. Anyways I think I need to correct that by myself. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks again.